Graph property using neighbourhood
I'm given the following definition of a type of graphs (I don't know the name of) but basically Let a graph $G = (V, E)$ such that if $d(v) \leq d(w)$ for $v, w \in V$  then $N(v) \subseteq N(w)$ or $N[v] \subseteq N[w]$.
Note:

$d$ is the degree of the vertex
$N(v)$ is the neighbourhood of $v$ and $N[v]$ is $N(v)$ $\cup \{v\}$

And I need to prove the following, a graph with such definition either has a $v$ with $d(v) = 0$ or $d(v) = |V| - 1$.
What I've tried:

Tried playing around trying to see if I could reach a contradiction with the degrees of the vertices but got nowhere.
Tried using induction on the size of $V$ and although I can prove that removing a random vertex I get a graph that still follows the definition (and thus can use inductive hypothesis) once I try to put it back in I cannot prove that there still is a vertex with degree $0$ or $|V|-1$.

I'd prefer hints over solutions so I can still try to prove it myself, but all are welcome.

Let vertex $w$ have the maximal degree; i.e. $d(v) \leq d(w)$ for all $v \in V$. What can you infer about the remaining vertices? I've added the full solution in the spoilers below for other readers who are interested, but I can edit this post if you want more hints.

By the given property, we get $N(v) \subseteq N[w]$ (since either $N(v) \subseteq N(w) \subseteq N[w]$ or $N(v) \subseteq N[v] \subseteq N[w]$). Hence, for every vertex $v$ with $d(v) \geq 1$, it must be connected to some vertex $v' \in N[w]$. Since edges are bidirectional, this then implies $v \in N(v')$, and so $v \in N[w]$. Therefore, every vertex $v \neq w$ with $d(v) \geq 1$ must lie in the neighbourhood of $w$.


1. If $d(w) = |V| - 1$, then $|N[w]| = d(w) + 1 = |V|$. So all vertices apart from $w$ lie in the neighborhood of $w$, which by definition means they are each connected to $w$ by an edge, and hence all have non-zero degree. Hence, $d(v) > 0 \; \forall \; v \in V$


2. Else if $d(w) =\leq |V| - 2$, then $N[w] \subset V$. Every $v \notin N[w]$ must have $d(v) = 0$, otherwise it would have to lie in $N[w]$. Since $|V \setminus N[w]| \geq 1$, there exists at least one vertex $v$ with $d(v) = 0$.


Thus either (exclusively) there exists a vertex v with $d(v) = |V| - 1$, or there exists a vertex v with $d(v) = 0$

